# Highcharts. Explicit colour for one point in HeatMap

Tags: highcharts

I have got a heat map with this colours:

```
colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        minColor: '#a50022',
        maxColor: '#007340',
        gridLineColor: '#000000',
        stops: [
            [0, '#a50022'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [1, '#007340']
        ],
    },
```

It works good, but now, I would like to define a color for some cases when I dont receive a value (between 0 and 1) but a string, so I can receive a "WARNING" and I would like to give it the colour red. For that I have tried to do this:

```
dataClasses: [{
          name: "WARNING",
          color: '#a50022',
        },
        ],
```

And when I create the series:

```
myData.push([column, row , "WARNING"]);
```

This doesnt work, it is shown in black. I have also tried:

```
myData.push({y:[column, row ,"WARNING"],name:"WARNING"});
```

And everything crashes with this, no data shown.

In this case, I will only receive strings, no values, so I could delete the stops, min, max and that stuff. So I would just need a "heat map" where I could define the colours for each string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
myData.push({y:[column, row ,"WARNING"],name:"WARNING"});
```

To:

```
myData.push({x: column, y:row, name:"WARNING", color: 'red'});
```

Comment: That works thanks, but this.point.value its null, could it be "WARNING"?

Comment: jsfiddle demo with issue? I'm not sure what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is now a setting you can specify in API http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.heatmap.nullColor

nullColor: Color

The color to apply to null points.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can set the color of a point in heatmap explicitly after generating it.
you can check out the below link.
[Demo, Explicit select and color change HeatMap](http://jsfiddle.net/swateja45/9snfzwd5/1/)

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
              <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
              <title>Highcharts Demo</title>  
            </head>

            <body>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


            <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>  
            <button id="getselectedpoints"> Select Point</button>
            <button id="changeColor"> Change color</button>


            <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

            var heatMapData=[];
            heatMapData.push({x: 1, y:1, name:"well_data1", color: 'red'});
            heatMapData.push({x: 4, y:5, name:"well_data2", color: 'green'});
            heatMapData.push({x: 6, y:10, name:"well_data3", color: 'blue'});
            heatMapData.push({x: 9, y:5, name:"well_data4", color: 'yellow'});

            var selfSelectedInHeatMap=false;

            var heatMapChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

                chart: {
                    type: 'heatmap',
                    marginTop: 40,
                    marginBottom: 80,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1
                },


                title: {
                    text: 'HEAT MAP'
                },

                xAxis: {
                        min:1,
                    categories: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                    gridLineWidth:1
                },

                yAxis: {
                        min:1,
                    categories: ['','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','m','n','o'],
                    gridLineWidth:1
                },



                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    margin: 0,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    enabled:false
                }, 
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    select: function () {
                                        selfSelectedInHeatMap = true;
                                        alert("selected "+this.name + ' (' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.y] +', ' +this.series.xAxis.categories[this.x] +')')
                                        doHeatMapSelectionWork(this.name);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b> (' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] +', ' +this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] +')';
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Wells Data',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                color: '#a4edba'
                            },
                            select: {
                                borderColor: 'black',
                                borderWidth:5
                            }
                        },
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: heatMapData,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false        
                        }
                }]

            });


            function doHeatMapSelectionWork(name)
            {
                if(!selfSelectedInHeatMap)
                {
                    var dataPoints = heatMapChart.series[0].data;
                    for(var i=0;i<dataPoints.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(dataPoints[i].name == name)
                        {
                            dataPoints[i].select();
                          break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                selfSelectedInHeatMap=false;
            }

            function changeColorForHeatMap(name)
            {
                var dataPoints = heatMapChart.series[0].data;
                for(var i=0;i<dataPoints.length;i++)
                {
                    if(dataPoints[i].name == name)
                    {
                        dataPoints[i].update({
                                color: 'pink'            
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $('#getselectedpoints').click(function () {
                doHeatMapSelectionWork('well_data1');
                });

                $('#changeColor').click(function () {
                changeColorForHeatMap('well_data2');
                });
            //]]> 

            </script>

            </body>

            </html>
```